# find coordinates of boxes that contain letters

Tags: c#, image, opencv

I want to calculate the coordinate of each box that contains a letter using openCv.
I will then crop each box and save it in a new image for ocr. In cvSetImageROI function the parameter CvRect is used which specifies the coordinate of box but in my case i have to find it.Please help me

[image]